# When will the edit post feature become visible?

Tags: discussion, review, edits

When I hover the mouse pointer over the *edit* below a post, It is showing me that **Suggested edit queue is full**

So, how many days will it take to render the *edit* feature for me so that I can edit the posts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll be able to edit as soon as the queue isn't full anymore. Could be a minute. Could be half an hour. Just as soon as one of the existing suggestion tasks gets completed (or maybe a few, because there are some circumstances where the queue can go over its 200 limit), the queue is no longer full. But that doesn't necessarily mean that *someone else* might not sneak in their edit before you visit another page and attempt to edit again.